# Border Radius only rounding the top of my divs?

Tags: html, css

I've been using the new CSS border-radius function for a while now, but I'm stumped today! I have a background image (120px x 60px) and have set a border radius of 5px, but it's only rounding the top two corners?!

The CSS code I'm using is here:

```css
#buttonRow {
    position:relative;
    width:980px;
    height:60px;
    margin-left:51px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    float:left;
}

#button {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    height:60px;
    margin-left:25px;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-image:url('../assets/buttons/generic_button.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#singleLineButton {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    height:60px;
    margin-left:25px;
    padding-top:20px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-image:url('../assets/buttons/generic_button.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#buttonText {
    width:120px;
    height:auto;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family: Adobe Kaiti Std R;
}
```

And the output is this:

[image: Rounded Divs]

Why is it only showing the top corners as rounded?!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Zulu

**EDIT**

Here is the HTML for those asking:

```html
<div id="buttonRow">
    <a href="http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/individual_table_management.php">
        <div id="button"><div id="buttonText">Individual Table Management</div></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/attendance_index.php">
        <div id="singleLineButton"><div id="buttonText">Attendance</div></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/school_members.php">
        <div id="singleLineButton"><div id="buttonText">School Members</div></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/search_choice.php">
        <div id="singleLineButton"><div id="buttonText">Search</div></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/school_details.php">
        <div id="singleLineButton"><div id="buttonText">School Details</div></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/user_management.php">
        <div id="singleLineButton"><div id="buttonText">Users</div></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at the styles applied in something like Firebug, or Chrome's inspector. We can't do much without the HTML, and preferably a link to a live demo of your problem.

Comment: Can you post your `HTML` sample here ?

Comment: Done! Sorry to say you won't be able to get on the site though as it's password protected... Unless you're hackers :P

Comment: Similar to the other comments, HTML would be appreciated.  I believe the issue, however to be related to using an image for your background.  Im not sure how images play with border-radius.  Also note that its generally a bad idea to use ids for elements like this.  Ids are meant to be unique across a page.  Use classes instead.  Further, your CSS declaration will only support the most modern browsers, and not the -webkit and -moz vendor variations of border radius. see the example at http://css3please.com

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/32Upf/   this jsfiddle seems to say that the border-radius works (using latest chrome version).  My guess is still that your image is messing with it.

Comment: Thanks for that.. Because they are rounded on all corners there, I'm guessing it is the image? Hmm, that's interesting because I've never had a problem with it before! Oh well, no worries. Thanks for all your help everybody!

Answer (score 4):

It might be that your image isn't long enough and thus you don't see the rounded corners on the bottom.  I ran into that today, actually.

I simply set a background color and it showed me what the issue was.  So, just modify your CSS to:

```css
background-image: #00ff00 url('../assets/buttons/generic_button.png');
```

or:

```css
background-color: #00ff00; /* bright green for contrast */
background-image: url('../assets/buttons/generic_button.png');
```

That will at least tell you if your image covers the whole area or not and you will know what to do from there.

Answer (score 2):

In CSS3 it's done like this:

```
border-top-right-radius: 8px;
border-top-left-radius: 8px
```

Comment: This does not answer the question!

Answer (score 2):

As previously answered, your image isn't large enough. Your div is 120x60px to match your image, but you have a padding-top of 10px, which extends the size of the div to 120x70px total--too large to show the rounding. Either change the size of your background image or resize the div to 50px tall--with padding, it'll end up at the proper size.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the bottoms are getting cut off from overflow. Make sure the containing element is tall enough to accomodate the heights of these or set the all the ancestor's overflow to `overflow: visible`.

Also, use jsfiddle.net to post live examples instead of just the CSS in a vacuum. CSS requires context.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @kmiyashiro - I've made the #buttonRow style much higher and still no change... And thanks for your advice about jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
#buttonRow {
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
#button {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    height:60px;
    margin-left:25px;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-image:url('../assets/buttons/generic_button.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background: red;
}
#singleLineButton {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    height:60px;
    margin-left:25px;
    padding-top:20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-image:url('../assets/buttons/generic_button.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background: red;
}
#buttonText {
    width:120px;
    height:auto;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family: Adobe Kaiti Std R;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonRow">
    <a href="http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/individual_table_management.php">
        <div id="button"><div id="buttonText">Individual Table Management</div></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/attendance_index.php">
        <div id="singleLineButton"><div id="buttonText">Attendance</div></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/school_members.php">
        <div id="singleLineButton"><div id="buttonText">School Members</div></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/search_choice.php">
        <div id="singleLineButton"><div id="buttonText">Search</div></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/school_details.php">
        <div id="singleLineButton"><div id="buttonText">School Details</div></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.zuluirminger.com/SchoolAdmin/user_management.php">
        <div id="singleLineButton"><div id="buttonText">Users</div></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using margin-top instead of padding top, I've had this issue recently and that seemed to fix it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation or code snippet, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33620271)